# How to redrawing the DataGridView as a result of the linq query

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

On the form is DGV, in which information is read from the database (using the linq2sql class).
There is a linq request, like:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {using (linqWorkDataContext db = new linqWorkDataContext())
        {
            var regi = (from r in db.Registrs.ToList()
                        group r by new
                        {
                            Date = checkBox1.Checked ? (DateTime?)r.date : (DateTime?)null,
                            Company = checkBox2.Checked ? r.company : null,
                            City = checkBox3.Checked ? r.city : null,
                            Country = checkBox4.Checked ? r.country : null,
                            Manager = checkBox5.Checked ? r.manager : null,
                        } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Date = checkBox1.Checked ? (DateTime?)g.Key.Date : (DateTime?)null,
                            Company = checkBox2.Checked ? g.Key.Company : null,
                            City = checkBox3.Checked ? g.Key.City : null,
                            Country = checkBox4.Checked ? g.Key.Country : null,
                            Manager = checkBox5.Checked ? g.Key.Manager : null,
                            Quantity = checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked || checkBox4.Checked || checkBox5.Checked ? g.Sum(s => s.quantity) : null,
                            Amount = checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked || checkBox4.Checked || checkBox5.Checked ? g.Sum(s => s.amount) : null,
                        }).Distinct();

            registrDataGridView.DataSource = regi.ToList();
        }
    }
```

The result of his work is given in the first screenshot. The user selects the required fields and displays the amount and quantity.
The problem is that only the selected fields are displayed (empty ones are displayed on the screen). That is, if the user chose date and company, then date, company, quantity and amount were displayed, and all the others were lost.
[image: my result now]
On the second screen, the company field is selected, that's what I want to achieve. (Screen from another project with another implementation)
How can I do that?

[image: what i want to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

The data you're returning still contains the table headers of `Registrs`, you've just ensured that all the data for these columns is null.

One way to correct this would be to update the visibility of the columns within the `DataGridView` to align with each `CheckBox`, like so:

```
registrDataGridView.Columns["Date"].Visible = checkBox1.Checked;
registrDataGridView.Columns["Company"].Visible = checkBox2.Checked;
registrDataGridView.Columns["City"].Visible = checkBox3.Checked;
registrDataGridView.Columns["Country"].Visible = checkBox4.Checked;
registrDataGridView.Columns["Manager"].Visible = checkBox5.Checked;
```

Columns can also be referenced using the index, e.g. `DataGridView.Columns[0].Visible`.

Comment: i am  get error "The object reference does not point to an instance of the object" on every of this string 
registrDataGridView.Columns["Date"].Visible = checkBox1.Checked; and so on...

Comment: Bit strange, I've tested it myself in VS2016 and it worked fine. Can you try using the indexes to see if that works?

Comment: Can you debug and ensure that `registrDataGridView` isn't null? As well as check that `registrDataGridView.Columns` has data?